# reload a div without reloading the whole page using ajax/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I'm doing a project which needs to be refreshed when user finish the form which is in the same page. Here is the code:

page1.jsp

```
 <div id="codeRefer">
    <input type="" type="text" name="numcode" id="numcode" value="42988715">
    <script language="javascript">
        var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
        var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
        var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
        var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
        var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
        var f = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
        var g = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
        var h = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
        var code = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h;
        document.getElementById("numcode").value = code;

        function ValidCaptcha() {
            var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('numcode').value);
            var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
            if (str1 == str2) {
                return true;
                alert(str1);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        function removeSpaces(string) {
            return string.split(' ').join('');
        }
    </script>
</div>
<input type="button" value="REFRESH" onClick="javascript:refer()">
<script language="javascript">
    function refer() {
        $('#codeRefer').load(window.location.href + '#codeRefer');
    }
</script>
```

Here what I'm getting is when ever I click the refresh the textbox value gets refreshed but, I'm getting another same 'refresh' button at the bottom of the first refresh button.
I don't know why an another button appears. Thankyou guys!

```
I think there is a bug in my code.
Which keeps repeating the whole content whenever I press the REFRESH button.
HELP me with this guys GURU'S.
```

Comment: you need to use iframes!

Comment: 'WORKING FIDDLE WILL BE ANSWERED'. You want someone to make a fiddle for you, right?

Comment: `{ return true; alert(str1); }` looks very nice

Comment: @Yury Tarabanko, yes you are right. Can you do that Please.

Comment: When you use `window.location.href + '#codeRefer'` you are actually loading the entire page within the div. You just need to load the contents of `#codeRefer` inside the div. Try `$('#codeRefer').html()`

Comment: @nightgaunt I did try your code, but it doesn't refresh the div. I appreciate all who are trying to help me out. Thanks to all you guys in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try move all the script out of `#codeRefer` and make an `empty()` call before loading html.

Like this:

```
$('#codeRefer').empty().load(window.location.href + '#codeRefer');
```

Edit: if you just want to refresh the div, I would suggest you to put what you want to load as a template and just load html from that template. Example:

```
<script type="text/template" id="refresh-template">
  <input type="" type="text" name="numcode" id="numcode" value="42988715">
</script>
```

and your javascript randomized number generation in your handler:

```
function refer() {
    $('#codeRefer').empty().load(window.location.href + '#refresh-template');
    // OR if you are just loading from the same page. just use .html() might be better
    // $('#codeRefer').html($('#refresh-template').html());

    var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
    var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
    var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
    var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
    var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
    var f = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
    var g = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
    var h = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
    var code = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h;
    document.getElementById("numcode").value = code;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L7wgU/1/

Comment: @Edward  I've tried this but this does the same like I have mention in the question. The code again makes a new Refresh-button appears at the bottom of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in this way only:

Create a pgae say ajax.html

```
<!-- ajax.html -->
<input type="" type="text" name="numcode" id="numcode" value="42988715">
<script language="javascript">
    var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
    var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
    var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
    var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
    var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
    var f = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
    var g = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
    var h = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
    var code = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h;
    document.getElementById("numcode").value = code;

    function ValidCaptcha() {
        var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('numcode').value);
        var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
        if (str1 == str2) {
            return true;
            alert(str1);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function removeSpaces(string) {
        return string.split(' ').join('');
    }
</script>
```

Then use this code in main html file say index.html

```
<div id="codeRefer">

</div>
<input type="button" value="REFRESH" onclick="refer()">
<script language="javascript">
    function refer() {
        $('#codeRefer').load('ajax.html#codeRefer');
    }
    refer();
</script>
```

Comment: @Waqar_Alamgir, thanks for responding, but I don't want another page for refreshing the code, because this is just part of a big form. Which I cannot use in this way. Thankyou for trying.

Comment: **is there another way to get only the 'numcode' value from the ajax?**

Comment: Yes, you can use JSON as well.

Comment: simply use html file. Put a 'numcode' in there, then use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function refer(ev) {
    $(ev.target).hide(); //hide the input button if want remove try .remove()
    var $currentCodeRefer = $("#codeRefer");
    $currentCodeRefer.ajax({
        url: window.location.href
    })
    .success(function(html) {
        var $newCodeRefer = $(html).find("#codeRefer");
        $newCodeRefer.empty().html($currentCodeRefer.html());
    });

//To receive the event data maybe need something like this:
$("buttonIDorClass").on("click", function(ev){refer(ev)});
```

Is not the better way, but is your need, i recommend have another ajax like the answer before, or have a javascript rendering and send json data and render in client side.

Comment: Quintana, I have tried like you have suggested, but not able to refresh the code. There is a bug in the code which i have wrote in the question, that makes repeat the text box and button just below. **I appreciate you have responded**.

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can use Ajax Form Submit and After submit clear the fields.